# How do I set port 8080 from my docker container to 443 in nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have nginx setup on my production server (I didnt use nginx in my docker/docker-compose for various reasons). Nginx is setup on my production server at ports 80 and 443 (when i go to http/https://my-domain.com it shows the nginx welcome page) and i have my node.js container running on port 8080 on my production server as well (when i go to http://my-domain.com:8080 it shows my app)

Is there a way I can tell nginx to map port 8080 to port 443 so my app will be displayed instead of the nginx welcome page?

Comment: This would be done with docker, yeah? Replace 8080 in your docker setup with 443. With standard node, assuming your node app listens on 8000 in the container, you would use 443:8000. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I set the port to 443 in my docker container it says port 443 is already in use and it wont create/run the container.

Comment: I figured out I need to set a proxy_pass in my location block in the nginx/sites-available/default.conf file to:
proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
and I got it to work - the app shows up on port 443 for the domain now, however it seems like it is missing the static files now - It looks like plain html with no css or images

Comment: Perfect, was just about to link the nginx docs for that!

Comment: I'm guessing I need to map a volume from my containers static files to the host, and then set the static files location in my nginx to the mapped volume for the static files to get it to work correctly? Does that sound about right?

Comment: If you're having more problems, I'd suggest checking for similar question on SO and making a new question if need be to keep things nice and clear.